# Mock useFetch hook with Jest

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, fetch

Im having this functional component with the useFetch hook:

```
function Foo(){

  const { data, isPending, run } = useFetch(`http://localhost:8080/users`);
}
```

How can I mock the data const here without doing an API call? The useFetch hook is from the library [react-async](https://docs.react-async.com/api/interfaces#usefetch-hook)

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";
import reactAsync from "react-async";

jest.mock('reactAsync');

it("test", async () => {
  const data = []
  const isPending = false
  const run = null
  reactAsync.useFetch.mockReturnValueOnce({ data, isPending, run });
});
```

[see here for other ways](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions)